# Export geojson from QGIS in SQL

Tags: django, postgresql, postgis, geojson, qgis

I've a geojson (postgres/postgis) file from QGIS.I want to import in my dabatase (used by Django).
Is it possible to generate a SQL command ? like a dump to import later ?

I've try ogr2ogr but there's an error, and, it's weird, the sql query in the error message is good :

```
# ogr2ogr -progress -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=db user=my_user dbname=my_database password=my_password" "04_GJ_ZM_4326-polygon.geojson" -nln my_table -append
ERROR 1: ERROR:  column s.consrc does not exist
LINE 1: ...nrelid = c.oid AND a.attnum = ANY (s.conkey) AND (s.consrc L...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "s.conkey" or the column "s.conbin".

ERROR 1: ERROR:  column s.consrc does not exist
LINE 1: ...nrelid = c.oid AND a.attnum = ANY (s.conkey) AND (s.consrc L...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "s.conkey" or the column "s.conbin".

ERROR 1: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

ERROR 1: INSERT command for new feature failed.
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

Command: INSERT INTO "my_table" ("polygon" , "number", "name", "department_id") VALUES ('0103000020E6100000010000000C0000001805C1E3DBFB174078D0ECBAB7184640FDA204FD850E194049F60835431E464055DD239BABB619405E8429CAA51F464084BA48A12CBC1940D044D8F0F40A464046B3B27DC8DB1940F3052D2460F845409966BAD749DD19401EA67D737FF7454048F8DEDFA0FD1840FB743C66A0F4454006D671FC50A91840D06394675EF64540AB23473A03C31840D3F4D901D7F945405ED5592DB0D71840F33977BB5E0046408E57207A5256184046B1DCD26A0846401805C1E3DBFB174078D0ECBAB7184640'::GEOMETRY, 44, 'PREALPES DE DIGNE', 4) RETURNING "id"
ERROR 1: Unable to write feature 0 from layer 04_GJ_ZM_4326-polygon.
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
translation of layer 04_GJ_ZM_4326-polygon (use -skipfailures to skip errors)
```

Thanks

F.

PS : There's an auto_increment "id" field to when inserting.

Comment: [This thread looks pretty much exactly like yours.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/342246/127552)